.NET 8 Blazor server web app : use different style libraries
I hope to have two different pages in the web app that use different style libraries, such as one using Bootstrap 3 and the other using Bootstrap 5
In .NET 7, two different implementations of _host.cshtml can be used. However, in the .NET 8 web app, there is no longer a host.cshtml file and it has been replaced by an app.razor file.
May I ask how to fulfill my above requirements?

You may try
@if (somecondition)
    {
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="......."]
        
    }
    else
    {
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="......."]
    }

.....

@code{
    // condition based on httpcontext
    [CascadingParameter]
    HttpContext? context{ get; set; }

}

in app.razor
when you navigate to pages in diffent styles,you need a full-page reload

Thank you, this solution is not ideal. Is there a way to implement two different App. razors, one using bootstrap 3 and the other using bootstrap 5? I implemented them through two different \ Hosts on net7

I don't think there would be a solution,because you have to map a certain App.razor  for only one time in program.cs :  app.MapRazorComponents()  ......

Also,in .net 7 and lower versions, host.cshtml is the page that all your components would be rendered  in it ( MapFallbackToPage("/_Host")).how did you fall back to different razor pages in .net 7?
